# How to disable auto preview for *.doc *.docx in finder?

Tags: finder, preview, ms-office

In finder, when I set the view mode as columns(cmd+3), finder will auto preview the file.But when I select doc/docx file the finder will be very slow even I cann't do anything for a while.How can I disable auto preview for doc/docx? Thx

Comment: I had the same problem. LibreOffice and OpenOffice's Quick Look Plugins were rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

Open Finder, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter `/System/Library/QuickLook/` to go to the [QuickLook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/) plugins folder. Click on `Office.qlgenerator`, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and rename the file to `Office.qlgenerator.backup`. Now, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and relaunch Finder. If ever you want to turn the plugin back on, simply remove the `.backup` from the file name.

Essentially, plugins tell QuickLook how to render a preview of a given file type. Without the Office plugin, QuickLook will by default show only the icon and information about the file (i.e. size, date created, etc.)

Note I'm pretty sure this removes QuickLook's capabilities of previewing OpenOffice files as well.

Comment: Yu might also be able to edit /System/Library/QuickLook/Office.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist, and remove "<string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>" from the LSItemContentTypes array.  Note that system updates may undo either this or @rkarbowski's suggestion.